# Changing the #foreach post loop ordering to ascending in loop.hbs

Tags: ghost-blog

At the moment there does not seem to be a way to declare the post order in the loop.hbs file. Newer posts are always on top, ordered descending. Is there an easy way to change the order to ascending?

Comment: Not at this moment in time. You would need to look at a client side solution.

Comment: I've used jQuery .reverse as a client side solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used jQuery .reverse as a client side solution